# Possible Causes of a Slow Sql View When Filtered

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a view in Sql Server 2008 that when performing just a:

```
SELECT * FROM [Table]
```

Will return roughly 40000 rows by 130 columns. Here are 6 runs with client statistics on (roughly 7 seconds average):

[image: Client Statistics (Unfiltered)]

Let's just assume those times are fine, the problem comes when a filter is applied. Here are 6 runs with client statistics on when I filter (roughly 6 seconds average):

[image: Client Statistics (Filtered)]

There are a few things that are annoying / frustrating about this:

1. The time difference is only about 1300ms on average.
2. Only 16 rows are returned in the filtered version.
3. The column that I am filtering is an int column, that has proper indexes.
4. The filtered SQL literally looks like:

   ```
   SELECT * FROM [Table] Where [IntColumn] = 15 -- returns 16 rows
   ```

I am coming to you guys because I am lost as to why the filtered version could possibly take so long. It should be extremely simple for the SQL engine to find those 16 rows right from the start of the execution and then calculate / look-up the values for the 130 columns. My questions really are:

1. What can cause this?
2. What should I be looking for to try and fix this?

Here are the anonymous execution plans (.sqlplan in .zip):

1. [Anonymous Sql Plans (Zippyshare)](http://www74.zippyshare.com/v/81997373/file.html)
2. [Anonymous Sql Plans (Dropbox)](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i2ejmeyjraawj2g/Anonymous%20Sql%20Plans.zip)

Comment: Execution plan of the view would help. Could you add the plan to the question?

Comment: I will work on getting an execution plan with anonymous table names as I am sure my company won't like me just posting it as-is.

Comment: Understood. Might I suggest good old paint to obscure the names.

Comment: Can we see what the view looks like as that is probably where the issue relies? Give it some anonymous names and columns and post that. Is it a normal view or an indexed view?

Comment: Paint won't help if you post what's really useful (the actual .sqlplan file rather than a barely useful screen shot). But search and replace should be easy.

Comment: It is a normal view (if by indexed-view you mean schema bound). I am working on cleaning up a .sqlplan. The view is huge.

Comment: The filtering is likely not to be the most expensive part of the query. Returning one row probably doesn't come back any faster either. The main cost of the query is going to be resolving the joins, returning ***130 columns***...

Comment: The fact that the view is huge may have a lot to do with it. One of the problems I've found with views is they don't necessarily apply your where clause in an efficient manner. I have had several views that performed much better when run as the query that makes up that view. Not sure if I'm phrasing that clearly.

Comment: @AaronBertrand - added sql plans

Comment: @Namphibian - added sql plans

Comment: @Zane - added sql plans

Answer (score 5):

It seems like a small portion of the plan is different depending on whether the filter is present. I'm trying to piece together what is happening, but that is some serious obfuscation trying to match up everything. Without knowing the definitions of things like Table1.Index9 and Table2.Index38 it's going to be very difficult to get specific help with the most expensive operators you have here.

In the meantime I have a couple of generic performance suggestions, other than reducing the complexity of the view and maybe considering having simpler views that don't output ***130 columns*** (try not to go cross-eyed looking at this join diagram):

[image]

(1) make sure your statistics are up to date on all the underlying tables. Almost every single operation is showing a massive gap between estimated and actual rows, which could help to explain suboptimal optimizer choices.

(2) get rid of two lookups by adding the following columns to the following indexes (probably as `INCLUDE` columns):

```
Table1.Column8  => Index3
Table1.Column43 => Index1
```

(3) some of these expressions are maddening, e.g.

```
CASE WHEN (
 Database0.Schema0.Table3.Column42 IS NOT NULL OR
 Database0.Schema0.Table3.Column42 IS NULL
)
AND Column56 IS NOT NULL
AND Database0.Schema0.Table3.Column55 IS NULL
AND Database0.Schema0.Table3.Column43 IS NULL
THEN (1) ELSE (0) END
```

Seriously? Look at that clause closely (and the view seems to be littered with dozens of these). No human could have done this on purpose. So what brain dead code generator produced this mess?

Comment: i was going to suggest updating stats, but then I always do, and thought 'nah!'

Comment: Thank you for the response. We've gone through and updated / created some smarter indexes and that has had minor improvements. I think the problem might be (as mentioned) the resolution of joins. It explains why filtering takes similar amounts of time to select *.